# Determining the flux of a vector field across a surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

The problem reads:

> Compute $\int_S \, \vec{F}(x, y, z) \cdot \vec{n} \ dS$, where $\vec{F}(x, y, z) = \left\langle x\ln(xz), 5z, \frac{1}{y^2+1} \right\rangle$, $S$ is the region of the plane $12x-9y+3z=10$ over the rectangular region in the $xy$-plane $D=\{(x, y) \; | \; 2 \le x \le 3 \; \text{and} \; 5 \le y \le 10\}$, and $\vec{n}$ points upwards.

The surface $S$ is defined by $z=f(x,y)=\frac{10}{3}-4x+3y$.

The differential is $dS=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\right)^2+1} \, dA = \sqrt{26} \, dA$.

The normal vector is $\vec{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{26}} \left\langle 4, -3, 1 \right\rangle$.

Since $z = \frac{10}{3}-4x+3y$,

$$\vec{F}\left[x, y, \left( \frac{10}{3} - 4x + 3y \right) \right] = \left\langle x\ln\left( \frac{10}{3}x - 4x^2 + 3xy \right), \left( \frac{50}{3} - 20x + 15y \right), \frac{1}{y^2+1} \right\rangle$$

$$\begin{align}
\int_S \, \vec{F}(x, y, z) \cdot \vec{n} \ dS
 & = \int_2^3 \int_5^{10} \left( 4x \ln\left[\frac{10}{3}x - 4x^2 + 3xy\right] - 50 + 60x - 45y + \frac{1}{y^2+1} \right) dy \, dx
\end{align}$$

It seems that this double integral becomes tedious to solve. Are there any mistakes I made in the steps towards setting up the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you made any mistakes. Maybe whoever setup the problem got confused and thought that $\vec n=(0,0,1)$? That would have made the integral trivial.

Comment: The reason I defined the normal vector $\vec{n}$ as such is because there is a level surface $$h(x, y, z) = 4x -3y + z - \frac{10}{3} = 0$$ such that $$\pm \nabla{h}(x, y, z) = \pm \left\langle 4, -3, 1 \right\rangle$$ I chose the vector $$\vec{v} =  \left\langle 4, -3, 1 \right\rangle$$ because this vector points upwards (i.e. the $z$ component is positive). From there, $$\Vert \vec{v} \Vert = \sqrt{26}$$ The unit normal vector is then $$\vec{n} = \frac{1}{\Vert \vec{v} \Vert} \vec{v} = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{26}} \left\langle 4, -3, 1 \right\rangle$$